# PHP Command Line & Browser Returning Different Results

Tags: wamp, php

I'm having an issue when running a script in a browser versus the command line. The script echo's the date 1/20/2012 when running within the browser, however when running within the command prompt it echo's tommorows date 1/21/2012. I have set my timezone to the

```
date.timezone = America/New_York
```

I'm running this script in the command line:

```
"c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.4\php.exe" -f "c:\wamp\www\site.com\cron.php"
```

Any ideas on why I'm getting two different dates from the same script?

Comment: This is just a guess, but it's possible PHP's CLI SAPI is accessing the system clock to determine the time while the WAMP version is using your windows time settings? Not really sure here. WAMP/windows can get funky sometimes with PHP. Does the same thing occur if you set the timezone at runtime with `date_default_timezone_set();` ???

Comment: I think I figured this out, I'm surprised more people havn't run into this type of issue.

WAMP has it's own PHP.ini file that resides within the Apache bin DIR. The command shell default PHP.ini used by PHP.exe is however in the same directory as..PHP.exe. Stupid WAMP!

Comment: Also, often times systems will provide 2 php.ini files, one for the command line, and another for the Web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your Apache and command line have same PHP. and both using the same php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

`php-cli`, `php-cgi`, & `php-fpm` all use different `php.ini` files by default.