# PHP version - Command line vs Web browser

Tags: php, version

Using phpinfo() in my browser, I see that my PHP version is 5.4.21. However, using "php -v" at a command line prompt, my PHP version reads 4.4.9.  I'm not the original PHP installer on this server, so I'm not sure why the mismatch.  However, I need the command line version to match (or at least, be close) to my browser version.

Is there a way I can update my command line PHP only?  If so, can someone point me to a solution?

I've found similar posts here on SO but none with my particular question and needed solution:

[different version php on command line and in apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554831/different-version-php-on-command-line-and-in-apache)

[PHP Command Line & Browser Returning Different Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950099/php-command-line-browser-returning-different-results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'where php' (windows) or 'which php -a' (rest of the world) to get the location of the php-binary you are using with the commandline. If the 5.X version shows up as secondary entry, one may consider deleting 4.x (after making sure, you have a backup around and ini-files are not shared between both versions). If it does not, modify your PATH to include the 5.5 location prior to the 4.X version (or delete/upgrade later)

This implies that you use php direclty without specifing a location.

If one of the versions is installed using the packet-manager of your choice, go check out their documentation before performing any steps.